# I keep getting the error "Node<E> is not generic; it cannot be parametized with arguments E" and "front cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, linked-list, queue

I'm making a linked implementation of a queue in Java. The problem is, it only displays the errors when I place it in a package (I'm using the default package) along with the other .java files needed (Queue, QueueDriver, etc.). It works fine outside the package. I'm using Eclipse.

```
    public class LinkedQueue<E> implements Queue<E>{

/**
 * Initialize the pointers
 */
private Node<E> front;
private Node<E> rear;

/**
 * Initialize size of list
 */
private int size;

/**
 * Initialize the linked queue
 */
public LinkedQueue() {
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    size = 0;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see Queue#isEmpty()
 */
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {      
    return (front == null);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see Queue#dequeue()
 */
@Override
public E dequeue() throws QueueEmptyException {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new QueueEmptyException("Queue is empty!");
    else{
        E temp = (E) front.getElement();
        front = front.getNext();
        size--;
        return temp;
    }
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see Queue#enqueue()
 */
@Override
public void enqueue(E element) {
    Node<E> x = new Node<E>(element);
    if(front == null){
        front = rear = x;
    }
    else{
        rear.setNext(x);
        rear = x;
    }
    size++;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see Queue#size()
 */
@Override
public int size() {     
    return size;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see Queue#front()
 */
@Override
public E front() throws QueueEmptyException {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new QueueEmptyException("Queue is empty!");

    return (E) front.getElement();
}
```

}

Comment: Check your imports. Verify that you're not importing some other JDK class or interface like org.w3c.dom.Node.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I only have three imports now. Queue.java, QueueEmptyException.java and QueueFullException.java

Comment: Move your classes to some package and either add `import your.package.Node;` yourself or use Ctrl+Shift+O to Organize Imports (in Eclipse) and selecting your class.

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work. What's weird is I also declared rear to be Node<E> but it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code for `Node` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that `Node` is not generic. It needs to be like

```
public class Node<E> {
    // your code here, using E as the data in the node
}
```